# grep and variable assignment in csh

Tags: awk, grep, csh

I am trying to assign a variable with a value I get from grep and awk. Something like below. Could anyone help me with right syntax?

Below is the snippet where I am trying to get full path to a file:

```
set name='egrep -i "vars\(design\)" foo.tcl' | 'awk '{print $3}''
set dir = $cwd
set fulldir = $dir/$name
```

Comment: try ``name=`awk '/vars\(design\)/{print $3}' IGNORECASE=1 foo.tcl` ``

Comment: Thanks Sundeep! That works.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use backticks to expand command, not single quotes. In addition, it looks like you've added a whole bunch of random `'`s?

This should work:

```
set name = `egrep -i "vars\(design\)" foo.tcl | awk '{print $3}'`
```

That being said, you don't really "need" to use `grep` here, and you can use only awk:

```
set name = `awk '/vars\(design\)/{print $3}' IGNORECASE=1 foo.tcl`
```

The part between `//` selects lines (just like grep).

---

You may also want to consider adding quotes to the other two `set` commands:

```
set dir = "$cwd"
set fulldir = "$dir/$name"
```

It's unlikely to happen here, but without quotes you'll run in to problems if `$dir` or `$name` contains spaces or other special shell characters. It's a good idea to always add them to prevent problems down the line.